# Unable to allow incoming traffic only through redis server port 6379 in Google compute instance using terraform script

Tags: redis, terraform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to access the external ip address of my google compute instance only using redis port (6379) but when access the ipaddress:6379 in browser, it is not connecting. I'm not sure if i'm missing anything. Can someone please help on this issue. I added the script I used below for the allow-redis firewall rule.

`````
````resource "google_compute_firewall" "default-allow-redis" {
name    = "default-allow-redis"
network = "default"

 allow {
  protocol = "tcp"
  ports    = ["6379"]
 }         

 source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 target_tags = ["redis-server"]
 disabled      = false  

 }
`````

I am expecting the output should be when i access the external ip address of my compute instance with redis port no 6379, it should show the message i added in the script.

Comment: Not working is not a good problem description. The key is connection refused or connection timed out. What type of browser are you using to connect to port 6379? Improved your question with more details.

Comment: Hi John..Thank you for correcting me. I edit it now and I'm using google chrome browser, tried in incognito tab too but still says site can't be reached through the redis port.

Comment: Are you trying to access port 6379 from a browser directly? Redis does not support http requests, you'll have to use a tool like telnet to check if the port is being listened to

Comment: Hello, Yes..I tried using telnet and redis cli and it is being listened to.Thank you Shameel. It worked for me.